# Беспроводные потоковые игры на Raspbian

Tags: raspberry-pi, streaming, gameserver, wireless

Я хотел играть в игры, которые должны быть размещены на Ubuntu PC на Raspberry Pi 3 B + с проводным геймпадом Xbox 360. Raspberry Pi работает на Raspbian Stretch без рабочего стола, только в командной строке. RPi подключен к маршрутизатору через кабель Ethernet. Хост-компьютер работает на Ubuntu 18.10 и подключен к маршрутизатору через Wi-Fi. Является ли это возможным?